# Calcular media en sql

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando calcular la media de puntos de una tabla llamada recetas, cada receta puede o no estar puntuada y puede ser puntuada por varios usuarios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se ve que consigo obtener los puntos de cada receta, pero esto provoca que las recetas estén duplicadas.
Lo que quiero es que me muestre la receta con la media de puntos sobre 10 en vez de los puntos que le dio un usuario.
La relación entre las tablas es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta sql que tengo es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT usuarios.nombre AS usuarios,
    recetas.id_usuario AS id_Usuario,
    recetas.nombre AS recetas,
    recetas.id AS id_Receta,
    recetas.preparacion,
    recetas.fecha_creacion,
    recetas.imagen,
    recetas.inf_nutricional,
    recetas.ingredientes,
    recetas.descripcion,
    tipo.nombre AS tipo,
    tipo.color,
    valorar.puntos
FROM recetas
JOIN usuarios ON recetas.id_usuario = usuarios.id
JOIN recetas_tipo ON recetas.id = recetas_tipo.id_recetas
JOIN tipo ON recetas_tipo.id_tipo = tipo.id
LEFT JOIN valorar ON recetas.id = valorar.id_receta
ORDER BY recetas.id;
```

Comment: Has intentado usar la función AVG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltaría agrupar por los datos de la receta y calcular la media de la valoración, teniendo en cuenta que puedes no tener puntos, la receta no habría recibido valoración.

```
SELECT 
    usuarios.nombre AS usuarios,
    recetas.id_usuario AS id_Usuario,
    recetas.nombre AS recetas,
    recetas.id AS id_Receta,
    recetas.preparacion,
    recetas.fecha_creacion,
    recetas.imagen,
    recetas.inf_nutricional,
    recetas.ingredientes,
    recetas.descripcion,
    tipo.nombre AS tipo,
    tipo.color,
    AVG(COALESCE(valorar.puntos,0)) AS media
FROM 
    recetas JOIN usuarios ON recetas.id_usuario = usuarios.id
    JOIN recetas_tipo ON recetas.id = recetas_tipo.id_recetas
    JOIN tipo ON recetas_tipo.id_tipo = tipo.id
    LEFT JOIN valorar ON recetas.id = valorar.id_receta
GROUP BY 
    usuarios.nombre,
    recetas.id_usuario,
    recetas.nombre,
    recetas.id,
    recetas.preparacion,
    recetas.fecha_creacion,
    recetas.imagen,
    recetas.inf_nutricional,
    recetas.ingredientes,
    recetas.descripcion,
    tipo.nombre,
    tipo.color
ORDER BY recetas.id;
```

Necesitas agrupar por aquellos campos que necesites recuperar, y aplicar la función AVG a la puntuación. Como la columna puntos puede ser nula puedes aplicar la función [COALESCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que evalúa la primera expresión que no sea nula, en este caso sería el 0.

Comment: El GROUP BY no puede tener el AS ya que da error

Comment: Cierto, error al copiar del SELECT.